# Альтернативы быстрого парсинга xml/html строки средствами python

Tags: python, xml, оптимизация, парсер

**Есть множество строк вида:**

```
a = '<httpSample t="51" lt="51" ts="1478854873129" s="true" lb="Enter SHI" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Sorting 1-21" dt="text" by="1749"/>'
```

**Задача: найти более быстрый способ получения из строк вида "a" значения атрибутов "t" и "lb" чем представленные (уточняю - главный критерий время, оно должно быть меньше, чем в представленных мною вариантах):**

1. Не хорошо (вдруг изменится количество атрибутов), но быстро (количество атрибутов неизменно):

   ```
   def x():
       b = a.split('"')
       xxx, yyy = b[1], b[9]
   ```
2. Хорошо, но в 6 раз дольше `x()`:

   ```
   import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 

   def y():
       tree = ET.fromstring(a)
       xxx = tree.attrib['t']
       yyy = tree.attrib['lb']
   ```

Можно воспользоваться для проверки:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit(x, number=3000000)
print timeit(y, number=3000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Например делать меньше операций в split.
Разбивать в 2 этапа, сначала по "lb=" на две части. 
Остаток тоже на две части по первой кавычке. 
Разбивая по  "lb=" или  "t=" решается вопрос с (вдруг изменится количество атрибутов)

```
def get_key(stri: str, key: str):
    return stri.split('%s="' % key, 1)[1].split('"', 1)[0]
get_key(a, 'lb')


def z():
    a.split('t="', 1)[1].split('"', 1)[0]
    a.split('lb="', 1)[1].split('"', 1)[0]
>>> x - 2.4 c
>>> z - 2.8 c
```

Получилось немного медленнее, при увеличении числа аргументов в строке, по идее будет быстрее

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант - он несомненно полезен для меня при изменении количества атрибутов - взял на вооружение), но для моей текущей задачи необходимо уменьшить время обработки. - Проверил ваш вариант на 1000 000 разных строчек с неизменным количеством атрибутов - работает немного медленнее(как вы и говорили), но поставил его в качестве except-а в альтернативу своему быстрому варианту - огромный + вам карму)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пул потоков, для 10млн строк прирост почти в 2 раза

```
import time
import multiprocessing

A = '<httpSample t="51" lt="51" ts="1478854873129" s="true" lb="Enter SHI" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Sorting 1-21" dt="text" by="1749"/>'
data = [A]*10**7

def x1(a):
    b = a.split('"')
    return b[1], b[9]

def x2(a):
    b = a.split('"', 9)
    return b[1], b[9]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # однопоточно
    t = time.time()
    list(map(x1, data))
    print(time.time() - t, 'no pool')

    # в пуле
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    t = time.time()
    pool.map(x1, data)
    print(time.time() - t, 'pool')

>>> x1 (24.128000020980835, 'no pool')
>>> x1 (13.368000030517578, 'pool')

>>> x2 (13.958999872207642, 'no pool')
>>> x2 (11.858999967575073, 'pool')
```

Если ограничить split(,9) как в x2(), то и однопоточно приблизится к времени пула.

Comment: изменил для python2

Comment: Спасибо большое, перепишу свой скрипт, потом отпишусь насколько его удалось ускорить + имеются дополнительные расчеты, которые тоже можно попробовать ускорить. Кстати добавлю комментарий о неработающей в python 2 конструкции с использованием with as - New in python version 3.3: Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. __enter__() returns the pool object, and __exit__() calls terminate().